# Azure Analysis Service diagnostics settings shows zero for row count

Tags: azure, logging, azure-analysis-services

I'm working on one azure function that streams diagnostic logs from EventHub instance (Azure Analysis Service instance --> EventHub namespace) to another data destination. Everything it's ok but recently I realized that column that reports the quantity of returned rows by the query is always zero. We have a similar solution for regular Analysis Service instances (installed on virtual machines) and such column actually has the right number of returned rows.

In more detail, I'm only considering the events "QueryBegin"/"QueryEnd" and I'm using "integerData" column to get this value like in our other solution but even if I use a Log analytics workspace to query it "directly" I see that row count is still zero. Something "funny" is that other columns it does report the information (time, cpu, duration, etc).

For example, I ran these 2 queries and as you can see row count is zero (integerData_s column)
[basic query in log analytics workspace linked to azure analysis service instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phkTy.png)

However, if we go to the result of the query we can see that actually it returned data.
[query does return rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl2kt.png)

could you tell me if this is the expected behavior? and if not, should I modify something in the azure analysis instance in order to get this value?

This is the current configuration of log analytics workspace that I'm using for debugging.
[LAW configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbjNw.png)

**Update:** integerData column has value "1" but only for the eventClass "notification"
[integerData column "1" for notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKx08.png)

Comment: more details about "integerData" column

Comment: IntegerData returns the actual number of rows returned by the query.

Comment: Refer SQL [Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/sql-stmtcompleted-event-class?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Hi @Sampath, thanks for the documentation! We checked that possible columns (integerData, RowCount) has information but they don't. IntegerData column always has zeros (except for "notification" eventClass) and RowCount column does not exist for Analysis services instances.